# bitcoinj Connect P2SH input transaction to the output transaction

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoinj

I have created P2SH address and send coins to the address 
https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/address/2N8Xu6rNAwssXtP2XPjSTuT2ViWQoPeHr3r

Next I want to send coins from 2N8Xu6rNAwssXtP2XPjSTuT2ViWQoPeHr3r address.

How to prepare P2SH transaction and connect it to the output script?

```
public static void sendFromP2SH(WalletAppKit kit, Address destAdd, Coin coin) throws AddressFormatException, InsufficientMoneyException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Transaction tx = new Transaction(TestNet3Params.get());
    tx.addOutput(coin, destAdd); //prepare destination output


    Wallet.SendRequest req = Wallet.SendRequest.forTx(tx);

    //TODO prepare P2SH input for output //https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/address/2N8Xu6rNAwssXtP2XPjSTuT2ViWQoPeHr3r
    Script script = P2SHScript(kit); //2N8Xu6rNAwssXtP2XPjSTuT2ViWQoPeHr3r
    TransactionOutput t = null;//... HOW TO CONNECT P2SH input transaction to the output ?
    tx.addInput(t);

    kit.wallet().completeTx(req);
    kit.wallet().commitTx(req.tx);
    kit.peerGroup().broadcastTransaction(req.tx).get();
}

    prepare script for the P2SH address  2N8Xu6rNAwssXtP2XPjSTuT2ViWQoPeHr3r
       public static Script P2SHScript(WalletAppKit kit) {
            ECKey pubClientKey = kit.wallet().getImportedKeys().get(0);
            ECKey pubServerKey = kit.wallet().getImportedKeys().get(1);
            return ScriptBuilder.createP2SHOutputScript(1, ImmutableList.of(pubClientKey, pubServerKey));
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hey! have you solved this problem? If yes, would you mind sharing the solution you found please?

Answer (score 0):

What about the following constructor?

```
public TransactionOutput(NetworkParameters params, Transaction parent, BigInteger value, Address to)
```

Inside the code it speculates over the 'to' address to check if it is multisig and creates the output script appropriately.